# Passing an Array from a function

Tags: powershell

I am very much puzzled with the way PowerShell is behaving with the arrays . In the below code I am adding three entries in the an array and when I check in the function it does give me the `array.Count` as 3, which is very much on the expected lines. Now I call the function at a different place  in the code and the element count just doubles from 3 to 6. I am sure doing something wrong here. Anyone has any idea/thoughts?

```
function ReadAPEnvInfoFrom () {
$pathList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $pathList.Add("aaa")
    $pathList.Add("bbb")
    $pathList.Add("ccc")

    Write-Host 'The count' $pathList.Count
    # returns 3 
    return $pathList
}

cls
$Array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
$Array = ReadAPEnvInfoFrom
Write-Host 'The count' $Array.Count
# returns 6
```

Comment: Show [mcve]. Where `$pathList` defined?

Comment: `$Array` should probably be `$pathList` in your sample code. If I run it the count is increased by 3 each time the function is called, just as expected.

Comment: Asgar : I just updated the code (for the issue )  ..apologizes for the initial miss from my side . I am sure I am missing something here .

Comment: `$pathList.Add("xxx")` -> `[void]$pathList.Add("xxx")`, also no need for `$Array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` as you replace `$Array` value on next line. And `return $pathList` -> `return ,$pathList` if you actually want to return `ArrayList` from function but not its elements.

Comment: P.S. If you want to notify previous commenter, then you should use this @Himanshu notation.

Answer (score 1):

To explain - each of your calls to the `Add()` method on the `ArrayList` is placing an index number onto the pipeline.  Even though they are not explicitly being returned, they are included in the value returned by the function.  So if you look at the value of `$Array`, you get:

```
0
1
2
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

You can either cast those calls to `[void]` at @PetSerAl is doing in the comment, or personally I prefer either assigning them to `$null`:

```
$null = $pathList.Add("aaa")
```

or to pipe the output to `Out-Null`:

```
$pathList.Add("aaa") | Out-Null
```

It comes down to personal preference there. ;)

Comment: Another option is to redirect undesired output: `$pathList.Add("aaa") > $null`. The return behavior of PowerShell functions is explained in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx), BTW.